# Can we enable / disable quick filters in Tableau 8.1?

Tags: filter, tableau-api

Can we enable/disable quick filters in Tableau 8.1?
For example, suppose there are two filters(multiple drop down box) "Employee code" and "Employee Name". If i select employee code from a list of employees , then the employee name filter should show the employee name but it should be disabled or non editable.
i.e user should not be able to deselect the employee name. Is this possible in Tableau?

Regards
Gautam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it is possible to set a workbook's permissions such that a group of users can view the workbook without being able to modify quick filters, it is not possible to disable a specific filter.

[Tableau Desktop Product Help:
Home > Publish and Share > Publishing to Tableau Server > Permissions](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#publish_workbooks_permissions_capabilities.html)